# What does this Google API error message mean?

Tags: google-api

Imagine you call an API to get an in-app purchase details. It has 3 params: package name (de facto app ID), product ID and a purchase token.

You get the following response: HTTP 400 Invalid Value with JSON body like this:

```
[{'message': 'Invalid Value', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'invalid'}]
```

Is your package name invalid? Is your product ID invalid? Or is your purchase token invalid?

Hint: all of the values you passed are valid.

Question: what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Answer: you're calling an incorrect API method. The purchase was not a product, it was a subscription.

I've wrote a ton of APIs myself and I would never ever return a HTTP 400 with such confusing output.

Google, you can do better.